# TestFlight test app goes wrong at beginning with CloudKit

Tags: ios, testflight, cloudkit

I have an app uses `CloudKit` to store data. When I am testing, installing from Xcode, it works well. When I submit to iTunes Connect, and install as beta App it does not go through some CloudKit startup processes. I do not now the exact problem. Can it be that I need CloudKit` **Deploy into Production**?

It is hard to test. I can not debug the TestFlight version, only the Xcode version, but that works.

Comment: you _can_ test the production container, if you add `<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment</key>
<string>Production</string>` to your `entitlements` file, even the debug build will access the production container. just make sure you delete that before uploading to App Store.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A TestFlight app will use the production CloudKit container. So you do have to deploy to production before using your app from iTunes connect.

Comment: I did deploy to production. but still, no data was being synced.  
What are the other moving parts

Comment: When you deploy to production it will only deploy the table structure. No data will be moved to production. You have to do that yourself.

Comment: I meant when I am using test flight app. data is not being synced between phone as it did on test version when I am side loading through Xcode.

Comment: Also, I am not writing any code it is just NSPreesistentClouldKitContainer. I am expecting it to store on a private database of user